# gem install pgすると失敗する。yum install postgresql-develでも解消しない。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

`gem install pg`すると以下のエラーが出ます。
実行しているのはEC2でOSはAmazon Linuxです。

```
$ gem install pg -v '0.20.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
current directory: /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pg-0.20.0/ext
/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20180206-457-e5bx4w.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0-static/pg-0.20.0/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pg-0.20.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ec2-user/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0-static/pg-0.20.0/gem_make.out
```

以下を実行しましたが、エラー内容は変わりませんでした。

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

また、psqlの設定ファイルは以下の通りです。

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/pg*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     35  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_archivecleanup -> /etc/alternatives/pg_archivecleanup
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     45  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_archivecleanup96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_archivecleanup
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_basebackup -> /etc/alternatives/pg_basebackup
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     41  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_basebackup96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_basebackup
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     27  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_config -> /etc/alternatives/pg_config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_config92 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql92/bin/pg_config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_config96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     32  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_controldata -> /etc/alternatives/pg_controldata
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     42  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_controldata96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_controldata
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     24  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_ctl -> /etc/alternatives/pg_ctl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     34  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_ctl96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_ctl
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_dump -> /etc/alternatives/pg_dump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     35  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_dump92 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql92/bin/pg_dump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     35  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_dump96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_dump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_dumpall -> /etc/alternatives/pg_dumpall
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_dumpall92 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql92/bin/pg_dumpall
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_dumpall96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_dumpall
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_isready -> /etc/alternatives/pg_isready
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_isready96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_isready
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     32  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_receivexlog -> /etc/alternatives/pg_receivexlog
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     42  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_receivexlog96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_receivexlog
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     32  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_recvlogical -> /etc/alternatives/pg_recvlogical
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     42  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_recvlogical96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_recvlogical
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     30  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_resetxlog -> /etc/alternatives/pg_resetxlog
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     40  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_resetxlog96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_resetxlog
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_restore -> /etc/alternatives/pg_restore
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_restore92 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql92/bin/pg_restore
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_restore96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_restore
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     27  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_rewind -> /etc/alternatives/pg_rewind
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     37  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_rewind96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_rewind
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     28  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_standby -> /etc/alternatives/pg_standby
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     38  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_standby96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_standby
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     31  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_test_fsync -> /etc/alternatives/pg_test_fsync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     41  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_test_fsync96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_test_fsync
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     32  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_test_timing -> /etc/alternatives/pg_test_timing
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     42  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_test_timing96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_test_timing
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     29  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pg_xlogdump -> /etc/alternatives/pg_xlogdump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     39  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pg_xlogdump96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pg_xlogdump
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 375360 10月 14  2012 /usr/bin/pgawk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     25  2月  6 08:47 /usr/bin/pgbench -> /etc/alternatives/pgbench
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     35  2月  6 08:36 /usr/bin/pgbench96 -> ../../usr/lib64/pgsql96/bin/pgbench
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root  15872  3月 17  2015 /usr/bin/pgrep
```

`libpq`を含むファイルがなかったのでこれが原因なのではないかと思い、以下を実行しましたがインストールできませんでした。

```
$ sudo yum install libpq-dev
読み込んだプラグイン:priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                           | 2.1 kB  00:00:00     
amzn-updates                                                                                        | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
23 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
パッケージ libpq-dev は利用できません。
```

`libpq-dev`がないため`gem install pg`でエラーが起きるのでしょうか？
上記が理由の場合どのようなコマンドでインストールできるでしょうか？
`gem install pg`のエラーを解決したいです。

恐れ入りますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: インストール済みのPostgresqlはどのようにしてインストールしたものでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Postgresqlは以下のコマンドでインストールしました。

Comment: $ sudo yum localinstall -y https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-ami201503-96-9.6-2.noarch.rpm
  $ rpm -ql pgdg-ami201503-96-9.6-2.noarch
  $ sudo yum install -y postgresql96 postgresql96-server postgresql96-libs postgresql96-contrib
  $ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql96 initdb

Comment: `/usr/bin/pg*`にあるのは設定ファイルではなく実行ファイルじゃないでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQLをPostgreSQLのリポジトリからインストールしたのであれば、関連するパッケージもそれに対応するものをインストールする必要があります。

postgresql96-develをインストールしてください。

Answer (score -1):

こういったエラーはpathが通っていないことが原因で起こることが多いです。
おなじpostgresをインストールするにしても、yum、sourceからコンパイル、パッケージ、homebrewなどと多彩で、gemのインストール時に必要とするファイルへのパスは自分で指定してやらないといけないパターンが多いです。
ただ、今回の場合は

```
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
```

と出ていますが直接そのファイルへのパスを通すのではない場合もあります。
（pg_configだったり）

[こちら](https://qiita.com/tarosay/items/b97e3f40d6b8acfa1bb7)など参考になさってみてはいかがでしょうか。

Answer (score -1):

gccがインストールされているか確認してみてください