# rails gem pg のインストールでlibpq-fe.hが見つからない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos

railsでgem pgをインストールしようとすると、

libpq-fe.hが見つからない というようなエラーがでます。

いろいろ情報はあるのですがcentosだと

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql-devel
```

を実行すればよいとのことですが、これでインストールして、次にbundle installすると

postgresqlのバージョンが古すぎるといわれます。

また新しいものをインストールしてもだめでループになっています。解決できないんですがどうしたらいいですか？

同じ質問がありましたが未解決っぽいですね
[gem install pgすると失敗する。yum install postgresql-develでも解消しない。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/41513/gem-install-pg%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E5%A4%B1%E6%95%97%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-yum-install-postgresql-devel%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E8%A7%A3%E6%B6%88%E3%81%97%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84)

Answer (score 1):

**自身の投稿**

問題: rails で　gem install pgすると失敗する。yum install postgresql-develでも解消しない。
環境: centos6

暫定的な解決策としてpostgresqlがあるディレクトリを指定してgem pg をインストールしたあとに、bundle installがとおるように設定することで解決するようです。（実際に解決はしました）

□私の場合はpostgresqlは以下にありました。

> /usr/pgsql-11

上記の場所を指定して gem pg をインストールします

```
$ gem install pg -- --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-11
```

□次にbundle installがとおるように設定します

```
bundle config build.pg -- --with-pg-dir=/usr/pgsql-11
```

これでbundle installが通るはずです

```
bundle install #OK
```